# Support for Intel WWAN module in HP Spectre x360

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, iwlwifi, wwan

I am planning on dual-booting my HP Spectre x360 13t-ap000, but I rely on the Intel XMM 7560 WWAN card for internet access, and I am wondering if I will be able to use it with Ubuntu. I saw this question on [Intel's Github page](https://github.com/intel/linux-intel-lts/issues/8) but I am unclear as to whether I will be able to get the module to work properly.

1. Is the module currently supported on any version of Ubuntu and
2. If it is, how would I go about getting it to work?

I am not very experienced with Linux, but I am willing to mess with things if I have instructions.

Comment: Module is not supported, nor are any of the related modules (see [#7 of the same Github page](https://github.com/intel/linux-intel-lts/issues/7) for questions on the 7360). [Intel doesn't want to answer](https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/Intel-XMM-7560-Modem/m-p/1223774). There is and [old and stale attempt](https://github.com/xmm7360/xmm7360-pci) to get the 7360 working on Ubuntu 20.04 and [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xmm7360-pci) is an attempt to get that working on Arch.

Comment: It is possible [ModemManager](https://github.com/enzingerm/ModemManager/tree/xmm7360/plugins/xmm7360) has *some* support for the 7360, so if you want to roll your own solution, I'd start there. Last I heard, Intel not supplying an API for Dynamic Power Reduction or RF output in general (to comply with FCC/SAR) is one of the main reasons vendors are not interested in working on a Linux driver.

Comment: See for example [this response](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/Linux-status-of-Fibocom-L850-Gl/m-p/4082434?page=10#4542304) by Lenovo on the L850-Gl, carrying a 7360. The same argument holds for the 7560 and 7660.

Comment: https://github.com/xmm7360/xmm7360-pci/issues/31#issuecomment-893756780 mentions kernel support specifically for that card. I might suggest trying a livecd first

Comment: Wow didn't expect any activity on this 2 years later. I've seen most of the GitHub and GitLab discussions, tried a kernel that officially had support and had no luck (same issues as pretty much everyone else in the ModemManager gitlab issue comment thread). Regardless, for me it doesn't matter anymore because my modem only supported Sprint on a hardware level, and Sprint stopped providing 4G service anymore since they were acquired by T-Mobile :(